# Popup de video youtube

Tags: link, youtube, popup

Eu criei um link em uma imagem para qdo clicar na imagem abre um popup centralizado na tela com o video do youtube, esta funcionando mas o que eu fiz não sei se seria o correto pois o phpstorm diz que tem erro, mas esta funcionando, alguém pode me ajudar?

Link=>

```
<a <label onclick="PopupCenter('https://www.youtube.com/embed/INQcOCgpOXs','785','680')"
        style="cursor:pointer;"></label>
    <img style="margin-right: -4.5px; border:solid 1px #ffffff" class="espaco"  src="imagens/thumb/atomizador_250lts_25_thumb.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Script do popup =>

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=650px' + w + ', height=450px' + h + ', top=100%' + ', left=' + left);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o erro que o PHPStorm está apontando é referente ao link, pois não faz sentido a tag `<label>` dentro do `<a>` da forma como está:

```
<a <label onclick="PopupCenter('https://www.youtube.com/embed/INQcOCgpOXs','785','680')"
    style="cursor:pointer;"></label><img></a>
```

O correto seria remover a tag `label`, e colocar o conteúdo dela no próprio `<a>`.
Também verifiquei que na chamada da função `PopupCenter()` na tag `<a>`, você não está passando o title como argumento, o código final ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<a onclick="PopupCenter('https://www.youtube.com/embed/INQcOCgpOXs','Titulo do Vídeo','785','680')" style="cursor:pointer;"><img style="margin-right: -4.5px; border:solid 1px #ffffff" class="espaco"  src="imagens/thumb/atomizador_250lts_25_thumb.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo acabei de descobrir e consertar vim aqui responder e me deparei com sua resposta. Agora ficou perfeito, obrigado.

Comment: Certo, precisando é só perguntar :)

Comment: Vlw, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se pode ser isso mas logo no começo você tá criando uma tag dentro de outra:

```
<a <label onclick = "PopupCenter('https://www.youtube.com/embed/INQcOCgpOXs','785','680')" style="cursor:pointer;"></label>
```

Acredito que precisaria criar o *label* dentro do *a*:

```
<a>
    <label onclick = "PopupCenter('https://www.youtube.com/embed/INQcOCgpOXs','785','680')" style = "cursor:pointer;"></label>
    <img style="margin-right: -4.5px; border:solid 1px #ffffff" class="espaco"  src="imagens/thumb/atomizador_250lts_25_thumb.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: Fazendo assim a imagem deixa de ser um link e não funciona, acabei de testar.